# AWS cloudwatch metrics are not shown in Prometheus query browser , however cloudwatch_exporter endpoint it shows all metrics

Tags: prometheus

Not able to see any metrics in the Prometheus query browser while cloudwatch_exporter endpoint shows all metrics.

[image]

Prometheus is able to **scrape** the metrics.
[image]
[image]

Comment: How have you checked? can you provide the query that was used?

Comment: query is aws_elb_healthy_host_count_average{job="aws_elb"}, which i am using in query browser.

Comment: Can you try using `{job=~".+"}` query check whether any metric available? if possible,  attach the Prometheus config file to the question body.